# Converting Python tuple of tuples of objects (list of mixed type) to Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pointers, numpy

Here is a data structure I set-up in Python which i would like to convert to a numpy array:

```
idx = tuple(tuple([None, None, None, None, None, 0, False] for i in range(S)) for j in range(A))
```

The first three entries are later assigned to pointers to arrays of the same type: [None, None, None, None, None, 0, False], which in turn can have their first three entries being pointers to these types of arrays, and so on.

The 4th and 5th entries are later assigned to pointers to dictionary entries {"admin": a, "devices":0}

The last two array entries are an integer and boolean.

How would I implement this as a "numpy" array? A conversion like

```
np.array(idx)
```

has problems, the first is that I have to go through the creation of lists and tuples in python which slows things down, can I do this more directly? Second, is how space for the None entries is allocated. They are different types and some later point to nested arrays of arrays. Thanks for any help.

Comment: This data structure is a horrible fit for NumPy. It's recursively nested, highly heterogeneous, and it's even got dicts in it. Why do you want to convert it to a NumPy array?

Comment: Looks like the only array that could hold this is `dtype=object`, which contains pointers to objects else where in memory. In effect a glorified (or degraded? ) list. Though with tuples it might try to construct a structured array with a compound `dtype`.

Comment: @user2357112, testing a speed issue for a contest. I need to trim about one second off to pass the last test. The original data structure was a forest of splay trees with nodes that point to dictionary entries based of keys that are a 2 point tuple that represents the vertices of an edge. The structure is dynamic, it works like a link-cut tree.

Comment: @mszlazak: Yeah, NumPy isn't going to help you with that.